# C++ Final executable with ifstream file requirements

Tags: c++, makefile, executable, filestream

So I have a query I haven't been able to find the answer for. I'm using Atom as a text editor and I have a makefile to compile my program. In my program I have reading from two text files using std::ifstream & std::sstream. When i compile my program using makefile and then run the program while my terminal is in that directory everything works perfectly.

BUT... when I dont use the terminal and I navigate to the run unix executable through folders and run the program, it cannot load the two text files.

I was wondering how do programmers go about this conundrum to produce a final program? Is there a way you can statically link files inside the program like you can with library headers so you don't have this issue?

Comment: You could provide the complete path for the file you want to read, rather than a relative one?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the program or how it's built. Instead it's about the *current working directory* (a.k.a. CWD) when you run the program. If you use relative paths for the files then those are relative from the CWD and not from there where executable program is located. If you run the program from a terminal, but not from the expected directory (just do e.g. `cd ..`) then it won't work either. Try using absolute paths instead.

Comment: Okay, that definitely works now, thanks. My next question is... if i was to send the executable to a friend and if they ran it... it obviously wouldn't work. How do you get around that issue?

Comment: If you can assume that your files are always in the same directory as your executable, you can use the path to the executable itself. You can use `/proc/self/exe` to get the full path to your executable.

Comment: thank you, ill look into that :)